# How is XP dispersed in Batman: Arkham Origins multiplayer?

Tags: batman-arkham-origins

At the end of multiplayer matches players are awarded the EXP they earned during that round. But I can't seem to figure out how EXP is dispersed? Sometimes I seem to get only weapon points, and then sometimes I get Overall Level EXP and other times I get Gang Level XP (and combinations of all three)?

So doing what different things in the round will get you EXP for which different areas (e.g. what actions gives you Gang Level XP, etc.)?